# passing parameter to directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('SuperCtrl').directive('listDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
      title:"="
    },
    templateUrl: '../templates/listWidget.html'
  };
});
```

I want to be able to reuse it and to do this I want to be able to pass parameter as a title.

In the template I have this fragment:

```
<h3 class="voice voice-brand pull-left" style="font-weight:bold">{{title}}</h3>
```

then in `index.html`:

```
<list-directive title="test1" ng-show="eventsActive"></list-directive>
```

But when I open this page I just see `{{title}}`.

What is the correct way to pass "title"?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks @MariaInesParnisari I  confused myself for a moment, I was doing it that way. Please could you take another look?

Comment: if you see {{title}} when the browser renders the page I think that you have some js issue

Comment: No it works elsewhere @MarcoMorelliMoretti.. It is for sure a syntax issue. Other angular elements are rendering fine.

Comment: what about link function , seems like you are not added a link function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `title` is a HTML attribute so avoid using this name for a directive input, unless you use the `data-title` syntax. Also, `=` scope data is used for 2-way binding which is not the case here (you just need a string) - in this case it's easier to use the `@` string value declaration. So:

```
scope:{
  listTitle: "@"
},
```

And

```
<list-directive list-title="test1"  ng-show="eventsActive"></list-directive>
```

And

```
<h3 class="voice voice-brand pull-left" style="font-weight:bold">{{listTitle}}</h3>
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now no longer see {{title}} but I also don't see my defined title...its just blank. Any further suggestions? Dev consoles no clues.

Comment: well you also need to use `{{listTitle}}`